# How to get the iterator (or the value) for "previous" item for given key of std::multimap?

Tags: c++, std, multimap

I would like to get the item that goes **before** given key, for my `std::multimap`.

For the item that goes after given key I could simply use `std::multimap::upper_bound` (it will return the element with key greater then given). But unfortunately, `std::multimap::lower_bound` returns the element with the "lower **or equal**" key.

The sample taken from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/lower_bound/:

```
mymultimap.insert(std::make_pair('a',10));
mymultimap.insert(std::make_pair('b',121));
mymultimap.insert(std::make_pair('c',1001));
mymultimap.insert(std::make_pair('c',2002));
mymultimap.insert(std::make_pair('d',11011));
mymultimap.insert(std::make_pair('e',44));

itlow = mymultimap.lower_bound ('b');  // itlow points to b
itup = mymultimap.upper_bound ('d');   // itup points to e (not d)
```

**How to get the iterator (or the value) for `a` when you give `b` as a parameter?**

Comment: Um, just decrement the iterator??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lower_bound`, but there are two edge cases you have to consider: it returns `begin()` and it returns `end()`:

```
auto itfound = mymultimap.lower_bound('b');
if (itfound == mymultimap.begin()) {
    // 'b', or something past 'b', is the first item
    // or the map is empty
    // what to do here?
}
else if (itfound == mymultimap.end()) {
    // there does not exist an item >= 'b'
    // what to do here? possibly std::prev(end()) ?
}
else {
    // ok cool, we found something in the middle
    // just back up
    --itfound;

    // do stuff with itfound here
}
```

Comment: Why does `end` need to be a special case? You should be able to decrement it the same as any other iterator.

Comment: @MarkRansom In case logically OP wants to do something different if there's no such element. Functionally, yeah, you can decrement `end()` just fine.

Comment: But `lower_bound` doesn't return `end` if the exact value isn't present, it returns the insertion point. That's only `end` if the key is larger than the largest key in the map.

Comment: begin will match end if the container is empty, which means the code inside your first if check potentially has UB unless you also check if its equal to end

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead and use `lower_bound`, then decrement the iterator you receive (after checking to make sure it isn't `begin`).

```
itfound = mymultimap.lower_bound('b');
if (itfound != mymultimap.begin())
{
    --itfound;
    // do something with itfound
}
```

You may need slightly different logic if the item isn't in the map, but that shouldn't be a hard modification.

Comment: Huh, I did not think about decrementing the `lower_bound`. Once I've red that it looks so obvious... Thank you, sir :)

Answer (score 1):

We know the following that for any sequenced container (i.e. `map`, `set`, `multimap` and `multiset`):

- `lower_bound(key)` returns the first entry >= `key`
- `upper_bound(key)` returns the first entry > `key`

Each function also returns `end()` in the event there is no entry >= / > `key`.

So we have functionality based on the operators > and >=.  We might reasonably ask, can we have functionality based on < and <= as well?

It is somewhat trivial to ask for the first entry < or <= `key` (this is either `begin()` or not in the container).  However it is meaningful to ask for is the last such entry.  Indeed, what you are asking for *is* the last entry < `key`.
For completeness we will consider the last entry <= `key` too.

Let's suppose we have such functions, what should they do if there is no such entry?  We could do a lot worse than return `end()`  too - it is a testable value and distinct from any successful case.  It is also consistent with both `lower_bound`, `upper_bound`, as well as `find` and a whole host of standalone search functions in the `<algorithm>` header.  The bottom line is that `end()` is routinely used to mean `no such entry' so this should be good enough for us as well.

As noted by Barry and Mark, calling `lower_bound(key)` and then decrementing will give us what we want, unless `lower_bound(key) == begin()`.  In this case, the first (and thus [joint-]smallest) entry is >= `key`, so there are no entries < `key` - precisely the scenario where we just said we should return `end()`.

For the case of looking for the last entry <= `key` we can do the same but with `upper_bound`, again returning `end()` to mean 'no such entry' when `upper_bound(key) == begin()`.

Lets call these functions `lower_bound_dec` and `upper_bound_dec` respectively:

```
// Find the last entry < key, returning end() if all entries are >= key
// Container can be any that implements lower_bound, e.g. std::map, std::multimap, std::set or std::multiset
template<typename Container, typename Key>
typename Container::const_iterator lower_bound_dec(const Container &container, const Key &key) {
    auto it = container.lower_bound(key);
    if (it == std::begin(container))
        it = std::end(container);
    else
        --it;
    return it;
}

// Find the last entry <= key, returning end() if all entries are > key
// Container can be any that implements upper_bound, e.g. std::map, std::multimap, std::set or std::multiset
template<typename Container, typename Key>
typename Container::const_iterator upper_bound_dec(const Container &container, const Key &key) {
    auto it = container.upper_bound(key);
    if (it == std::begin(container))
        it = std::end(container);
    else
        --it;
    return it;
}
```

We might also define iterator based functions, that mirror `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` and can operate on any sorted range with **bidirectional** iterators:

```
// Find the last entry < key, returning end() if all entries are >= key
// last must be reachable from first, and all entries in sorted order between them
template<typename Iterator, typename Key>
Iterator lower_bound_dec(Iterator first, Iterator last, const Key &key) {
    auto it = container.lower_bound(first, last, key);
    if (it == first)
        it = last;
    else
        --it; // requires bidirectional iterators
    return it;
}
```

`upper_bound(first, last, key)` and the forms that take a comparator left as exercises to the reader / anyone who wants to earn rep by editing! :)

**TL/DR:**
Use lower_bound and then decrement, with the caveat that "decrementing" `begin()` yields `end()` to mean 'no such entry.'